# jqGrid pager textbox size

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

On our jqGrid pager the page number textbox size is off.  Some of our other site CSS is liking causing an issue.  Anyone know how to fix this?

This is our footer:

![alt text][1]

And an example from the jqGrid demo site with a correct size:

![alt text][2]

---

Update 3 (removed prior 2 updates)..

The issue appears to go away after changing:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
```

To:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Why is this?

Is there a way you can provide some CSS to explicitly set the CSS of the pager input text box?

Comment: It can has different reasons. A code example which reproduce your problem will be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't posted the whole HTML and JavaScript code. I created almost the same [example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/fontsize.htm) which has no described problem. So you problem is in the part which you not posted. For example, has your HTML code `<!DOCTYPE html ...>` element?

Comment: Added a link to more code at end of post.  We do have this doctype: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">`

Comment: @Marcus: The new version of the code has more unreferenced parts (more CSS documents, more javascript documents). Try to reduce the code so that you has a HTML page with all references needed and where the problem exists. First of all you can try to remove all javascripts and all custom formatters (with no data they are not used). Then reduce the number of CSS files. At the end you will have a code close to my example. If you not find yourself the problem I will be able to **reproduce** your problem and hopefully will find the reason.

Comment: Will try to do this.  Is there something wrong with the DOCTYPE definition we have?

Comment: Updated post one more time..  why would DOCTYPE have this affect?

Comment: @Marcus: I am not sure, but `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">` is **really** very old and it limited support for style sheets and no support for HTML 4 features. CSS from jQuery and jqGrid use some advanced features. Probably it is the reason. Try with `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"` or better with `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` of my favorite XHTML 1.0 Strict, but verify the page in http://validator.w3.org

Comment: Indeed the HTML 4.01 DOCTYPE fixes the problem - except it breaks other non related functionality in our app.  So I don't think I can use it right now..  But I did see that `.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-input{height:18px;width:18px;}`  seems to solve the issue.   Does that sound right?

Comment: @Marcus: I am not sure that the issue with the pager size is the only problem which you can has. On you place I would do use HTML 4.01 DOCTYPE (or XHTML) and analyse the existing problem with the "Trace Styles" feature of the Developer Tools of IE8.