# Jqgrid rowlist Selection box

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a pager inside of my jqgrid, on the pager i have rowList option, where people can choose if they want to have 10/20 or more rows showed up at one time. The problem is that selection box is not viewed fully.

example :  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/unledevx.png/

[image]

Are there any way to show it completely? I have tryed to find CSS options for this item, but couldnt find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS setting from [the line 58](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css#L58) of the `ui.jqgrid.css`

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-selbox {
    font-size:.8em;
    line-height:18px;
    display:block;
    height:18px;
    margin: 0em;
}
```

is responsible for the font size. One sees another problem with very wide pager input field (`ui-pg-input`).

The reason can be the following:

- no or wrong `<!DOCTYPE html ...>` at the beginning of HTML file (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998402/jqgrid-pager-textbox-size/3998710#3998710))
- add `input.ui-pg-input { width: auto; }` to fix the pager input field. See [this post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/fixing-problems-with-the-calculation-of-the-grid-width-for-asp-net-mvc-projects/&value=1671&type=9&include=0&search=2&ret=all) additionally if you use ASP.NET MVC.
- the usage of "compatibility view" of IE (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262775/jqgrid-and-compatibility-view-mode-in-ie8/5263387#5263387) inclusive comments). You can solve the problem (if it exists) with adding of `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` in the `<head>` of the page.

In any way you have CSS problem. You can use IE developer tools (press <kbd>F12</kbd> to start) to examine the styles.